# nohup multiple sequential commands

Tags: linux, nohup

I need to `nohup` two commands, one after another. The second command has to be executed AFTER the first command. Here are the commands:

```
tar -zcf archive.tar.gz.tmp mydir
mv archive.tar.gz.tmp archive.tar.gz
```

I need the commands to run in the background, but obviously not both at the same time. The second command has to be run after the first command is complete. I tried this:

```
nohup tar -zcf archive.tar.gz.tmp mydir ; mv archive.tar.gz.tmp archive.tar.gz > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

but the commands don't run in the background. The bash prompt waits until the two commands are complete before giving me another prompt. I need them to run in the background.

If I do:

```
nohup tar -zcf archive.tar.gz.tmp mydir > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

That runs in the background perfectly. It's only when I try to do more than one command.

I also tried:

```
nohup tar -zcf archive.tar.gz.tmp mydir > /dev/null 2>&1 & ; mv archive.tar.gz.tmp archive.tar.gz > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

But that didn't work either. Invalid syntax or something. I'm sure there is a way to do this but I'm just not sure the syntax.

The only alternative I can think of is to put the commands into a `.sh` file and nohup that file, but that isn't necessarily something I can do on the linux system I have to implement this on (privileges limitations etc).

Comment: I know this is an old question. Independent of the chosen nohup solution you should join your two commands with `&&` instead of `;` so the second command only is executed if the first succeeded (`&&` is a specific bash command).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest solution: Create a shell script with

```
 #/bin/sh
 tar -zcf archive.tar.gz.tmp mydir
 mv archive.tar.gz.tmp archive.tar.gz
```

And use `nohup myscript`. Possibly with some extra documentation in the script.

(Yes, I am a sucker for documentation. Especially when working with multiple people or when you might someday leave the job and your successor needs to figure out why".)

---

An alternative might be to start a new shell for a subtask (in this case your tar and move)

nohup `$(tar -zcf archive.tar.gz.tmp mydir; mv archive.tar.gz.tmp archive.tar.gz)

---

Alternative 2:

nohup ```tar -zcf archive.tar.gz.tmp mydir ; mv archive.tar.gz.tmp archive.tar.gz```.

I really prefer the script though. The comments in it might be quite useful when you or someone else looks at he script in a few years and wonders why it was done this way.

On a unrelated note: How the heck do I post an anser with a backtick in it? (The command for a shell to 'use this command ; feed the output to another command as input`).

Comment: Well, good practice dictates that you should use `$()` rather than back-ticks, anyway.  But then that would be identical to my answer.

Comment: actually backticks will try to evaluate the result of the expression inside -, so depending on the commands, this may not work.

Comment: alternative 2 does not seem to work : mkdir testdir touch testdir/testfile then run nohup `cd ; cd testdir; ls` return failed to run command `testfile'...

Comment: "succor" means a much needed help, such as comforting someone who is distressed, and doesn't seem entirely appropriate here. Possibly you meant the common English phrase "I am a sucker for X" .

Answer (score 5):

I think you need parentheses.

`nohup $(tar -zcf archive.tar.gz.tmp mydir; mv archive.tar.gz.tmp archive.tar.gz) >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

Comment: It still waits until both commands are complete before returning to the command prompt.

Comment: What's the shell? I get a prompt immediately in Bash. Final `&` backgrounds the whole job.

Comment: Hit enter.  You get a prompt.

Comment: Ah yeah okay it is running correct at the bash shell. I tried running it via PHP's `exec()` command but it waits for the second command to run. Strangely if I do just one command it behaves as expected though...

Comment: @Jakobud: The example of nohup php exec() is in the php manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php and it references http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748432/insane-crond-behavior-keeps-making-defunct-bash-processes/3750028#3750028

Comment: @Iain that solution worked perfectly in PHP. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bash wrap?

```
nohup bash -c 'tar -zcf archive.tar.gz.tmp mydir > /dev/null 2>&1 ; mv archive.tar.gz.tmp archive.tar.gz > /dev/null 2>&1' &
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `screen` to give the commands and detach from the screen session:

```
screen
tar -zcf archive.tar.gz.tmp mydir && mv archive.tar.gz.tmp archive.tar.gz
ctrl-a d to detach
```

The commands will run as with nohup.

Comment: screen -dmS would be better, then.

Comment: Maybe but I think easier to understand showing things separated: open screen, give the commands and detach than everything on the same line, having to give a name to the session.

Comment: screen is great for interactive use, but is not appropriate for scripting or automation.